# Timeout for active socket connection?

Tags: java, sockets

How can I specify a timeout on an active `java.net.Socket` connection? I don't mean the timeout of `.accept()` that blocks the process. I'd like to set a timeout that starts to count when `accept` method takes a connection, until the client connection is closed/output stream is returned.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. it is possible with socket.setSoTimeout()